# Javax.Faces Library: build path incomplete error

Tags: java, spring, maven, project

I have a Maven Web Project and I have a problem with the Javax.Faces library.

I've added the library to my pom.xml but I get an error message.
I attached a few screenshots:

My Problem is:

[image: Problem]

And that problem show in markers:

[image: Errors list]

My Project Facets File:

[image: Project Facets File]

My Build Path:

[image: Build Path]

And my pom.xml file:

[pom.xml](http://textuploader.com/rdhg)

How can I resolve those error messages?

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seams that everything is fine with your configuration and maven dependencies get imported and added to project classpath.

Howerver I can see you are specifying version **2.2** in *JSF* Facets configuration while you are declaring a **2.1.10** *jsf-api* version in your pom file.
So try to update your *jsf-api* and *jsf-impl* artifacts version to an onward one:

```
<!-- JSF 2.2 dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Second, the "jsf-impl" will not you?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake and keep me up to date if this helped solving the issue :)